# Ubuntu 18.10 slow boot on SSD with dual boot Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, boot, ssd, performance

I have a Lenovo y50, core i7, 16gb RAM with a 1TB Samsung Evo 6 SSD setup with the following structure -

Ubuntu 18.10 - full disk encryption on 750gb. (No swap partition for the ubuntu)

Windows 10 - no encryption on 230gb.

Thing is, the Windows 10 boots up in 3s while the Ubuntu 18.10 boots up in approximately 2 minutes.

Here are some commands i ran to identify whats wrong,

Output of systemd-analyze - https://pastebin.com/AfAZ1gKN

```
Startup finished in 2.150s (firmware) + 39.294s (loader) + 11.414s (kernel) + 12.606s (userspace) = 1min 5.466s
graphical.target reached after 12.595s in userspace
```

Output of systemd-analyze blame - https://pastebin.com/CSkp5ViH

```
      7.241s plymouth-quit-wait.service
          6.608s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          2.073s systemd-udev-settle.service
          1.557s snapd.service
          1.455s vmware.service
          1.334s dev-mapper-system\x2droot.device
           902ms vboxdrv.service
           711ms udisks2.service
           669ms plymouth-start.service
           648ms networkd-dispatcher.service
           637ms snapd.seeded.service
           616ms vmware-workstation-server.service
           578ms systemd-journal-flush.service
           555ms vmware-USBArbitrator.service
           538ms upower.service
           533ms systemd-logind.service
           457ms systemd-resolved.service
           429ms fwupd.service
           417ms ModemManager.service
           378ms snap-gimp-130.mount
           352ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-57.mount
           325ms accounts-daemon.service
           317ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-57.mount
           289ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           286ms snap-onlyoffice\x2ddesktopeditors-31.mount
           282ms NetworkManager.service
           281ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-82.mount
           267ms apparmor.service
           250ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-70.mount
           247ms snap-gimp-165.mount
           241ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           237ms systemd-rfkill.service
           236ms apport.service
           219ms keyboard-setup.service
           213ms thermald.service
           213ms rsyslog.service
           207ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1198.mount
           206ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-70.mount
           203ms snap-core-5662.mount
           196ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-406.mount
           195ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-23.mount
           187ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-206.mount
           183ms dev-loop10.device
           181ms snap-core18-941.mount
           180ms dev-loop11.device
           176ms dev-loop8.device
           172ms avahi-daemon.service
           170ms wpa_supplicant.service
           167ms incron.service
           160ms packagekit.service
           156ms bluetooth.service
           154ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-238.mount
           154ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-45.mount
           149ms dev-loop7.device
           148ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-701.mount
           148ms dev-loop13.device
           145ms snap-core18-782.mount
           143ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-61.mount
           143ms dev-loop12.device
           140ms pppd-dns.service
           134ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-124.mount
           133ms dev-loop14.device
           132ms gpu-manager.service
           128ms switcheroo-control.service
           127ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-CA59\x2dC858.service
           125ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-352.mount
           124ms dev-loop6.device
           122ms dev-loop1.device
           121ms systemd-journald.service
           118ms dev-loop16.device
           118ms dev-loop3.device
           114ms dev-loop4.device
           113ms dev-loop9.device
           111ms bolt.service
           111ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-254.mount
           108ms dev-loop15.device
           107ms dev-loop5.device
           100ms grub-common.service
           100ms snap-core-6673.mount
            99ms gdm.service
            95ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-77.mount
            85ms dev-loop18.device
            84ms dev-loop17.device
            83ms motd-news.service
            80ms networking.service
            76ms systemd-udevd.service
            76ms kerneloops.service
            75ms dev-loop2.device
            73ms systemd-fsck@dev-mapper-system\x2dboot.service
            72ms polkit.service
            68ms dev-loop19.device
            67ms colord.service
            63ms dev-loop0.device
            59ms user@1000.service
            56ms lvm2-pvscan@253:0.service
            49ms lvm2-monitor.service
            46ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
            43ms systemd-modules-load.service
            41ms dns-clean.service
            39ms dev-loop20.device
            37ms dev-loop23.device
            35ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
            32ms kmod-static-nodes.service
            30ms lvm2-activation-early.service
            30ms grub-initrd-fallback.service
            30ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
            29ms systemd-sysctl.service
            29ms boot.mount
            28ms dev-hugepages.mount
            26ms dev-mqueue.mount
            26ms boot-efi.mount
            25ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
            24ms lvm2-activation.service
            23ms plymouth-read-write.service
            23ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
            23ms systemd-sysusers.service
            22ms console-setup.service
            21ms vboxweb-service.service
            20ms systemd-update-utmp.service
            20ms ufw.service
            19ms systemd-remount-fs.service
            18ms ubiquity.service
            15ms vboxballoonctrl-service.service
            15ms systemd-random-seed.service
            14ms dev-loop21.device
            13ms systemd-user-sessions.service
            13ms vboxautostart-service.service
            13ms systemd-cryptsetup@system.service
            11ms ifupdown-pre.service
            10ms sys-kernel-config.mount
             9ms rtkit-daemon.service
             9ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
             9ms snapd.socket
             8ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
             8ms setvtrgb.service
             8ms dev-loop22.device
             3ms blk-availability.service
             3ms openvpn.service
```

Output of sytemd-analyze critical-chain - https://pastebin.com/tUCWuzcA

```
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @12.595s
└─multi-user.target @12.594s
  └─vmware-workstation-server.service @11.978s +616ms
    └─vmware.service @10.521s +1.455s
      └─network-online.target @10.497s
        └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @3.887s +6.608s
          └─NetworkManager.service @3.594s +282ms
            └─dbus.service @3.564s
              └─basic.target @3.512s
                └─sockets.target @3.512s
                  └─snapd.socket @3.503s +9ms
                    └─sysinit.target @3.498s
                      └─systemd-timesyncd.service @3.207s +289ms
                        └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @3.149s +46ms
                          └─local-fs.target @3.140s
                            └─run-vmblock\x2dfuse.mount @10.802s
                              └─local-fs-pre.target @2.689s
                                └─lvm2-monitor.service @2.640s +49ms
                                  └─lvm2-lvmetad.socket @236ms
                                    └─-.mount @231ms
                                      └─system.slice @231ms
                                        └─-.slice @231ms
```

Any help to reduce the boot times would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How did you dualboot it? What's the main bootloader? Does Ubuntu boot directly from grub? Any performance improves after disabling encryption?

Comment: Dual boot was from grub. I select either Windows or Ubuntu from the Grub menu. It will be difficult to disable full disk encryption except doing a full install. The setup works fine, however Ubuntu takes too long to boot (about 1min plus) while Windows 10 boots in 3s. This is an SSD.